# DoesntHave method Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

What am I wanting to do?
I have 2 tables, being them..
Layout and DenyList (layout that is not to be used).

And what do I want to do?
I want to retrieve a layout in which it does not exist OR the expiry date has already passed.

In theory, I created a scope (this one below), which should bring the layouts according to the rule I mentioned above, but apparently it is not working, because even if a layout exists in the denylist table, it is returning, it seems that it is not taking into account my query.

```
return $query->doesntHave('deny_list', 'and', function ($q) {
            $q->whereRaw('date(date_expire_at) <= ' . Carbon::now()->format("Y-m-d"));
        });
```

Table layouts

```
id - pk
name - string
type - string
```

Table layout_deny_list

```
id - pk
layout_id - integer
date_expire_at - timestamp
```

Model Layout

```
class Layout extends Model
{
 
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    /**
     * @var string The database table used by the model.
     */
    public $table = 'layouts';

    /**
     * @var array Validation rules
     */
    public $rules = [
    ];

    public $hasMany = [      
        'deny_list' => LayoutDenyList::class,
    ];

    public function scopeNotExistDenyList($query)
    {        
        return $query->doesntHave('deny_list', 'and', function ($q) {
            $q->whereRaw('date(date_expire_at) <= ' . Carbon::now()->format("Y-m-d"));
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you simply missing a `get()` at the very last `});` for the return? ... maybe `})->get();`

Comment: Before debugging your code, elaborate on this question. how did you relation those table on your model? which one did you created scope,  local or global? how did you call the scope?

Comment: @JSTECH I added in post original more information.

Comment: Where did you find that code `public $hasMany = [...];`? I think it should not worked like this. @Crazy

Comment: I am using the OctoberCMS, This CMS uses laravel, so hasMany is a shortcut to hasMany that laravel does.

Comment: @JSTECH Note so the HasMany I'm using can consider the same traditional hasMany from Laravel, ok?

Comment: @Crazy, sorry to say but I don't how OctoberCMS code flow.